# C# without lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have lambda expression:

```
cake.PropertyChanged += (mSender, eventArgs)
               => listOfFinishedOrders.Items.Insert(count,cake.NameOfCake + eventArgs.PropertyName);
```

How to write this without using lambda expression?

Comment: Just wrap code in method and set PropertyChanged to that method

Comment: Your lambda appears to have at least one, possibly two or more captured variables. There are several different possible ways to convert to without a lambda expression, but if you don't provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing exactly the full context, it won't be possible to provide the best answer. Please improve your question. Also, it would be helpful to understand why you don't want to use the lambda; it's a useful feature...why try to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this usage of a lambda expression (a very common one), all that's really happening is the code declares an anonymous methods. The C# compiler handles this by creating a real method, albeit one with no visible name in the source code (hence "anonymous"). To rid yourself of the lambda syntax (again, why?), "all" you need to do is move the anonymous method body to a named method.

In the simplest case, the new named method can be put in the same class. This works when there are no captured variables; all of the code in the method uses only things that are visible in any normal method of the class. If that's the case, then you can do something like this:

```
void M()
{
    // some other stuff

    cake.PropertyChanged += N;

    // some other stuff
}

void N(object mSender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    listOfFinishedOrders.Items.Insert(count, cake.NameOfCake + eventArgs.PropertyName);
}
```

However, in many cases one or more variables are "captured" by the anonymous method. In this case, the C# compiler will generate a class to go with (and contain) the anonymous method. In this class will also go fields to support the variables that were "captured".

Indeed, in your example, it seems very likely that one or more of the variables used in the anonymous method body are captured variables.

You can emulate the behavior of the C# compiler yourself:

```
class Captured1
{
    private readonly int count;
    private readonly Cake cake;
    private readonly ListBox listOfFinishedOrders;

    public Captured1(int count, Cake cake, ListBox listOfFinishedOrders)
    {
        this.count = count;
        this.cake = cake;
        this.listOfFinishedOrders = listOfFinishedOrders;
    }

    public void N(object mSender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        listOfFinishedOrders.Items.Insert(count,
            cake.NameOfCake + eventArgs.PropertyName);
    }
}

void M()
{
    // some other stuff

    Captured1 c = new Captured1(count, cake, listOfFinishedOrders);

    cake.PropertyChanged += c.N;

    // some other stuff
}
```

**Note:** I've taken some liberties above, guessing at types such as `Cake` and `ListBox`. You didn't provide enough context in your question for anyone to know for sure what those variables are, so I just tried my best. I assume you can provide the correct types in your own code if I happened to guess wrong.

Now, in the above, note that all of the fields are read-only. They are copied to the new class when the instance is created. But this might or might not be what you really want. In particular, in the real lambda scenario, changes to captured variables are observed by code in the lambda method body, even after the lambda delegate has been created.

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I'm loathe to speculate on this particular example. It may not apply at all in your scenario.

But in general: you would address that kind of scenario by making the field `public`, and not `readonly`, so that it could be used as an actual variable in the context where the instance is created. This would allow changes to the variable to be visible within the lambda method body, as well as allow changes to the variable that occur within the lambda method body to be visible to code executing after the lambda delegate is invoked.

I'll note that your event is a member of the `cake` object itself. This strongly hints (though again, lacking a good code example does not guarantee) that the `mSender` object is in fact always going to be the `cake` object. If so, you can simplify the `Captured1` class by not including the `cake` field, and changing the `N()` method to look like this:

```
public void N(object mSender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    listOfFinishedOrders.Items.Insert(count,
        ((Cake)mSender).NameOfCake + eventArgs.PropertyName);
}
```

All of the above is a simplified version of what the compiler actually does. There are a number of variations on the scenario and to enumerate all of the possibilities here would involve essentially reimplementing the compiler behavior, a task far too broad for StackOverflow. But I hope the above gives you a good enough idea of the basic approach:

- Move the anonymous method body into a named method. If that can compile without errors, then…great, you're done!
- If that didn't work, then one or more variables in the named method are no longer valid (having taken them out of the scope in which they are defined). In that case, you will need to create a helper class (as the `Captured1` one above) where you can store the variable values. The named method will also go into that new class. Create an instance of the class and use the named method to subscribe the event (or whatever…lambdas are used in a lot of other ways, and this basic technique will work in any of those scenarios).

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to use a lambda there, you will have to use a separate method. At that point, you will run into the problem that you are using variables which may or may not be accessible to your method since they are declared locally. If that’s the case for `listOfFinishedOrders` and/or `count`, you will have to store them somewhere where the method can access them too (usually as private members in the class):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    // private members for those local variables
    private int count;
    private ListBox listOfFinishedOrders;

    public void SomeMethod ()
    {
        // Some code that has `cake`, `listOfFinishedOrders` and `count`
        // as local variables. This is also where the lambda was before.

        // store the values in the type
        this.count = count;
        this.listOfFinishedOrders = listOfFinishedOrders;

        cake.PropertyChanged += CakeChanged;
    }

    private void CakeChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cake cake = sender as Cake; // sender is the original cake

        // `listOfFinishedOrders` and `count` are instance members
        listOfFinishedOrders.Items.Insert(count, cake.NameOfCake + e.PropertyName);
    }
}
```

Of course, this solution assumes that there is only a single value for `count` and `listOfFinishedOrders` which may not be the case (especially if you have multiple cakes you want to attach the event too—which however works out of the box because the cake is determined from the event sender).

Depending on your actual situation there might be cleaner ways to solve it, somewhere in the middle between Peter’s solution, which mimics the functionality of lambdas very closely, and mine that just assumes a simple environment.

Comment: The above can work in certain scenarios. However, you should include the caveat that it's definitely a limited approach; it would not work, for example, if there are multiple `cake` objects, each needing its own copy of captured variables, due to them being captured in different contexts (e.g. in a loop).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to write this code without a lambda since it's a one liner (the ideal use case for lambdas). But here is how you could do it, if the lambda body is longer:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() { cake.PropertyChanged += HandleCakeChanged; }
    void HandleCakeChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: And how well does that work if `listOfFinishedOrder`, `count`, and/or `cake` were local variables in the original context? You've left out all of the _interesting_ parts of the answer.

Comment: IMO that stuff will become obvious once OP has the syntax for pulling that line out of the lambda and tries to do so.